# Android Studio creates no Main Class and layout file

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I try to create a new Android Studio Project.

Till today creating new projects was done by a simple dialoge window in which you had to determine the project name and the minimal API Level. After doing that the project structure opened and a MainClass and a layout file had already been created.

Now there is a window where you have to determine whether it should be created by Gradle or be just a simple Java Project.

OK it may be an update... Now the strange part starts...

I now get asked to enter an artifactId and a GroupId. (Is this an equivalent to the project name?)

After another new but less confusing window the project was created but the Project structure has changed:There was no module "app", there was altough a Java directory existed no (usually autocreated) Main class or layout file.
(Project structure and the non existing Mainclass can be seen in the picture)

When trying to open an existing  project the IDE throws two errors saying that there was no File named "name of the project".iml and app.iml.

I have already tried to reinstall Android Studio.

Is this an update?
Did I mess up settings?

[image: The new useless project structure]

Comment: I wasnt even asked. I know what you mean: there should be a dialog window but there is just the unusual gui I have described.

Comment: What AS version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by deleting not just android studio in system settings but also in registry.
After reinstallling it finally worked.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> There is a window where you have to determine whether it should be created by Gradle or be just a simple Java Project... I now get asked to enter an artifactId and a GroupId.

Sounds like you made a Gradle project, not an Android app.

> The new useless project structure

Maybe useless for an Android project, not a plain Java codebase.

> Did I mess up settings?

Possibly. The Android IntelliJ plugin may not be loaded properly